# Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 3 of EncryptByKey function encryption

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption

I'm currently doing an assessment and having quite some trouble with SQL encryption, I need to encrypt three of these columns on registration which are varchar but then they will need to be converted to varbinary for AES_256 encryption. I already have the keys and certificates set up it's just the T SQL that I need help with at the moment.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Register
@Email nvarchar (60),
@Password varbinary (256),
@Fname varchar (24),
@Lname varchar (24),
@DoB date,
@HomePhoneNo nvarchar (20),
@MobileNo nvarchar (20),
@SecretQuestion1 varbinary (256),
@SecretQuestion2 varbinary (256)
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT @Email FROM Customers.Customers)
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.Register
ROLLBACK

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY Password_Key_DB
        DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE PasswordEncryption
        SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT INTO Customers.Customers
VALUES 
(
@Email, 
ENCRYPTBYKEY(Key_GUID('Password_Key_DB'), @Password, CONVERT (varchar, @Password)),
@Fname, 
@Lname, 
@DoB,
@HomePhoneNo, 
@MobileNo,
ENCRYPTBYKEY(Key_GUID('Password_Key_DB'), @SecretQuestion1, CONVERT (varchar,                 @SecretQuestion1)),
ENCRYPTBYKEY(Key_GUID('Password_Key_DB'), @SecretQuestion2, CONVERT (varchar,     @SecretQuestion2))
)
END
GO
```